# Intersection of two irreducible hypersurfaces of mutual coprime degree in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

Let, $Z_1 =Z(f)$ and $Z_2 =Z(g)$ be two irreducible hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$of degree $m$,$n$, where $g.c.d(m,n)=1$ and $1 <n< m$.

Is it true that $Z_1 \cap Z_2$ is always an irreducible curve?(we assume that the intersection is nonempty)

My guess is no because if we compute its ideal, then we have, $I(Z_1 \cap Z_2) = I(Z_1) \cup I(Z_2) = \sqrt {(f)} \cup \sqrt{(g)}$, which need not be necessarily even an ideal(so therefore not a prime), though we know  $\sqrt {(f)}$ ,$\sqrt {(g)}$ are prime ideals.

So is it true that if we impose some condition on one of the hypersurfaces then it's irreducible? for instance if we assume one of the $Z_1$ or $Z_2$ is smooth.

In order to show that it's a curve if we assume dim ($Z_1 \cap Z_2) \neq 1$,then if it's $2$,then by Hartshorne exercise $1.10(d)$(chapter -$1$), we have $Z_1 \cap Z_2 = Z_1 \Rightarrow Z_1 \subset Z_2 \Rightarrow \sqrt{(g)} \subset \sqrt{(f)}$ , from where I don't see any contradiction even after using $g.c.d(m,n)=1$ and degree comparison.When dim $Z_1 \cap Z_2 =0$ it's even more unclear.

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: The intersection of two smooth surfaces can be reducible: take a quadric and intersect it with its tangent plane at any point.

Comment: @LazzaroCampeotti,I think it will be atleast a curve(by my argument).What if we assume one of them to be very general? i.e $Pic(Z_1) \cong \mathbb Z$.Is the curve irreducible then?

Comment: Yes, it will certainly be a curve (although I cannot follow your argument). See Section I.7 of Hartshorne. As for your second question, this seems likely but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: @LazzaroCampeotti,exactly by projective dimension theorem